# Specify Allowed IPs for WAF Admin Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-waf

I just set up a WAF for my **Elastic Beanstalk load balancer**. One of the rules I added was this one:

```
AWS-AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet
```

Which only allows certain IPs to access the admin page of my elastic beanstalk app (`/admin`). **How can I set these allowed IPs?** Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a managed rule created by AWS and does not support parameters being passed into any of their rules. It is used to prevent unauthorised access to specific paths commonly known (such as `wp-login.php` for WordPress). It will also be looking for behavioural patterns and other common attacks.

The documentation identifies the following:

> The Admin protection rule group contains rules that allow you to block external access to exposed administrative pages. This might be useful if you run third-party software or want to reduce the risk of a malicious actor gaining administrative access to your application.

If you want to allow specific IPs to be whitelisted you can combine rules with an [IPSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_IPSet.html) rule.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I guess I am struggling to understand really what the rule does then?

Comment: All it says is `Inspects requests for URI paths that are generally reserved for administration of a webserver or application. Example patterns include sqlmanager.`. I believe it would prevent pages such as `wp-login.php` or `phpmyadmin` from access without being localhost.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but how would this be useful unless you could choose which pages and which IPs? Thanks so much for your help, Chris!!

Comment: It primarily blocks accidentally exposing admin URLs that you would not want exposed when you install software. For example if you had phpmyadmin accidently installed on a host, there's an ability for a malicious actor to use this to connect to your databases, similarly for a firewall appliance it stops the configuration interface accidently being publicly accessible.

Comment: Got it, so for my case, I am trying to restrict access to the Django admin page. This would not be able to do that, right?

Comment: It would be easier to use an IPSet to allow traffic as the highest priority, and a rule set containing a single of matching paths starting with the admin path. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-group-creating.html

Comment: Will check that out. Thanks so much Chris!!

Comment: No problem, let me know if there’s any follow up questions and I’ll try to help. Have a great day :)